# Integration of C# and prolog

Tags: c#, prolog, integration

I have to write a program with c# in visual studio. I want to call Prolog functions from C# code. Is there any way of this? Thanks so much.

Comment: You could try http://sourceforge.net/projects/cs-prolog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for example: [Prolog.NET](http://hodroj.net/prolog/) or [P#](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/stg/research/Psharp/) or [A COM Wrapper](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/ls/lsadotnet.htm)

Comment: thanks but prolog.net comes with a setup. And after the installation, the message says that i have successfully installed prolog.net. but there is nothing to run on the desktop or anywhere. how do i use it? is it a component that i can reach from visual studio? thanks again.